# What can I use instead of document.write

Tags: javascript, blogger, pagespeed

```
   if (a.indexOf('?q=') == -1 && a.indexOf('.html') == -1) {
        if (a.indexOf('/search/label/') == -1) {
            currentPage = 'page';
            if (locationrl.indexOf('#PageNo=') != -1) {
                currentPageNo = locationrl.substring(locationrl.indexOf('#PageNo=') + 8, locationrl.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            document.write('<script src=\'' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=dataFeed\'><\/script>')
        } else {
            currentPage = 'label';
            if (a.indexOf('&max-results=') == -1) {
                postResults = 20
            }
            if (locationrl.indexOf('#PageNo=') != -1) {
                currentPageNo = locationrl.substring(locationrl.indexOf('#PageNo=') + 8, locationrl.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            document.write('<script src="' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary/-/' + postLabel + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=dataFeed&max-results=1" ><\/script>')
        }
    }
```

What can I use instead of document.write in this code? Google Pagespeed tells me not to use document.write

Comment: `document.body.appendChild`  or `document.head.appendChild`, or `$(document.head).append(...html...)`

Comment: How use that code?

Comment: For the jquery one it's straight forward.  Just plugin your constructed script string into that append method and you're good.  For the appendChild versions, you would need to `document.createElement('script')`, set all the attributes, and then use that Element in the appendChild call

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a tag using JavaScript then your best bet and most common solution is to use the `createElement` method:

```
document.createElement()
```

This method takes in a string which specifies the tag you want to create. Lets say a div:

```
document.createElement("div")
```

Then, to actually insert this element in the `DOM` you need to append it to another tag, lets sey `body`

```
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
const div = document.createElement("div")

body.appendChild(div)
```

Finally to set attributes like src or href you need to call the `setAttribute` method which takes in 2 strings - `name` and `value`:

```
div.setAttribute("background", "red")
```

Comment: `document.body`, you don't have to look it up by tag name.

Comment: True. It's been so long since ive written vanilla JavaScript, i actually miss it :)

Answer (score 0):

One gotcha for injecting script tags via DOM elements versus `document.write` is that dynamically created scripts inserted with DOM methods are created with `async` true. This may or may not matter in your case, but if you want the script to block later script execution as it does with `document.write` without an `async` or `defer` attribute, you have to make sure to set `async` to `false` explicitly on the DOM element.

```
if (a.indexOf('?q=') == -1 && a.indexOf('.html') == -1) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = false;

  currentPageNo = (locationrl.indexOf('#PageNo=') != -1)
    ? locationrl.substring(locationrl.indexOf('#PageNo=') + 8, locationrl.length)
    : 1;

  if (a.indexOf('/search/label/') == -1) {
    currentPage = 'page';
    script.src = `${home_page}feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=dataFeed`;
  } else {
    currentPage = 'label';
    if (a.indexOf('&max-results=') == -1) {
      postResults = 20
    }
    script.src = `${home_page}feeds/posts/summary/-/${postLabel}?alt=json-in-script&callback=dataFeed&max-results=1`
  }
  document.head.appendChild(script); // or wherever you want to inject it
}
```

Of course, having `async` is *better*, so if you don't need to block later scripts from executing you can leave the `script.async = false` off. But it looks like you're setting global JavaScript variables, so it's likely that you do want the non-async behavior.

Comment: You helped me a lot. Thank you.